# How can i make buttons, text, and images layed over another image resize with the image?

Tags: html, css

How can I make buttons and images that are placed over a banner be responsive, as in when the browser is made smaller the image gets smaller however buttons and images and text do not shrink with the banner. What can i add to my code to make this all shrink correctly. here is part of my css and html code below. any help on this would be very appreciated, thanks!

```css
#putimage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 38%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#button2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 22%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#button3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 3.4%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 75%;
}

.headshot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 47px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  left: 7.8%;
}

.photos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  left: 51.6%;
  font-size: 220%;
}

.photoscount {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 55.8%;
  font-size: 220%;
}
```

```html
<div id="putimage">
  <img src="http://partneredaffiliates.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/21875637_167049423848751_1262488588_o.jpg" width="100%" height="500px" />
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Subscribe">
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Message">
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="VIP Photos">
  <img class="headshot" src="http://partneredaffiliates.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/21767500_167049813848712_2048841584_n.png">
  <div class="name">
    <font size="30" color="white">ELO <strong>KITTY</strong></font>
  </div>
  <div class="photos">
    <font color="white">PHOTOS</font>
  </div>
  <div class="photoscount">
    <font color="white">72</font>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries to change style attributes according to screen size.

For instance, change the size of the `.headshot` image to 20% of its original when the screen has a minimum width of `200px` and a maximum width of `700px`. Please run the snippet and then switch to fullscreen to see that in action.

Here is a [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) with more information on media queries.

```css
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width:700px) {
  .headshot {
    width:20%;
  }
}

#putimage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 38%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#button2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 22%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#button3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 3.4%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 75%;
}

.headshot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 47px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  left: 7.8%;
}

.photos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  left: 51.6%;
  font-size: 220%;
}

.photoscount {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 55.8%;
  font-size: 220%;
}
```

```html
<div id="putimage">
  <img src="http://partneredaffiliates.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/21875637_167049423848751_1262488588_o.jpg" width="100%" height="500px" />
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Subscribe">
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Message">
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="VIP Photos">
  <img class="headshot" src="http://partneredaffiliates.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/21767500_167049813848712_2048841584_n.png">
  <div class="name">
    <font size="30" color="white">ELO <strong>KITTY</strong></font>
  </div>
  <div class="photos">
    <font color="white">PHOTOS</font>
  </div>
  <div class="photoscount">
    <font color="white">72</font>
  </div>
</div>
```